# Microsoft Dynamics 365 Portal - Website Files

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, portal

I'm new on **Microsoft Dynamics 365** and I'm trying to create portal in D365.
my question is about the address of Related files to my website on server. I need this address to locate my files such as **Page Templates** and etc...

Comment: A properly detailed answer would be way too long... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/ Here you can find the official documentation, with all the information to start working with Portals.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored as records inside Dynamics 365.

The [Portal Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/configure-portal) app lets you do advanced configuration actions on your portal. The app is available after the database on Microsoft Dataverse is created successfully.